# Xamarin.Forms Get the object of a ListView when an Entry in the ListView is changed

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have an item class with values for name and price which are stored in an SQLite database.  I'm displaying them in a Listview with a Label for the name and an Entry for the price.

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView">
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Path=price, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:c}'}" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="updateItem" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to make it so when the Entry change is completed it will update the item in the SQLite database with the new value for price, however, I don't know how to retrieve the Item which was finished from the Listview.  I think I need to use the following method but I don't know what to put in it.

```
async void updateItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code to update the item with the SQLite database with the new price
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your updateItem handler, then BindingContext of the item should be element from the ItemSource that is being updated

```
async void updateItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MyItemType) ((Entry)sender).BindingContext;

    //Code to update the item with the SQLite database with the new price
}
```